# Status code for updating with same values

Tags: http-status-codes

what should be the status code for updating an entity with same values

> ex if i have an entity employee in my database with attributes employee_id=123,employee_name='xyz',gender='male'

***what should be the Status code for Update request fired with the same values  ***
i am confused between  304 not modified or 409 conflict whichi one would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the success code would be appropriate (200, 204).

as you can see, 304 has caching in mind. You don't cache in your case.

> The server generating a 304 response MUST generate any of the
>   following header fields that would have been sent in a 200 OK response
>   to the same request: Cache-Control, Content-Location, Date, ETag,
>   Expires, and Vary.

Also 409 means error, if the value is updated to what you wanted(although there is no change) it would be better to view it as success case.